# Full package completion in Webstorm

Tags: intellij-idea, javadoc, webstorm, google-closure

I have a project, where I need to type JSDoc comments with types in Webstorm.

Provided code completion almost does what I want.
For Example I can type "@param {Err" and press  to get auto completion for "@param {ErrorService". Sadly, what I would really want is to auto complete it to "@param {my.project.ErrorService".

WebStorm already know this type, since it show it in tooltip. Is there a way to make Webstorm generate fully qualified path in JSDoc autocompletion for types?

Comment: not sure I follow you... When you enter my. and hit Ctrl+space, WebStorm will suggest 'project' and then 'ErrorService'. See also http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-2355#comment=27-612697

Comment: Yes, but I paths in my project are very often longer than my.project. . There are sometimes up to 5 nested levels. Typing all 5 of them is very tedious. It would be really nice if I could just type the object and get the full path.